# How to create a file in a specific project directory folder

Tags: java

---

I want to create a file in textfolder but the file cannot be created in the folder. Assuming "textfolder" has already been created.

[image]

For example, the output of Location is ".\textfolder"

Comment: Please post your code in text for easier investigation, reproduction and eventually receiving better help.

Comment: Copy your code into your question as text, not as an image.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question.

Comment: Your filename is .\textfolder\aFile.txt Location is .\textfoleder\ , so you created two text folders

Answer (score 1):

If your file name is ".\invoices\aFile.txt" , that means your `folderDir` points to `.\textfolder\invoices\aFile.txt` . I see two problem here

1. The `folderDir` is pointing to a file not a folder or directory. Consider renaming to targetFile or something.
2. There is middle folder missing, since `invoices` folder is not created by the command `file.createNewFile()`, nor does it create any intermediate folders. Use `Files.createDirectories(hostingFolder)` to create the hosting folders for your aFile.txt, where `hostingFolder` points to `.\textfolder\invoices\`

## Update

```
private static final String Location = "." + File.separator + "textfolder";
public static boolean save(String filename) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Location,filename);
        //create folder if not exist
        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(Location))) {
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(Location));
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    save("aFile.txt");

}
```

Based on your description, try the above code. Be-aware that for `File file = new File(Location+filename,"UTF-8")`, was trying to create a file pointing to `.\textfolder\aFile.txt\UTF-8`, i.e. "UTF-8" was considered as part of the path name. Java uses this constructor `public File(String parent, String child)` if the first argument is a string.

Comment: I realized there was a mistake as i used `Files.createDirectories(invoice)` instead of `Files.createDirectories(textfolder)`. However, i removed `currDir `, `folderDir` and changed the command to `File file = new File(Location,"UTF-8")`. The file is still not added into the folder any solution to this?

Comment: try my updated code.